# Как добавлять элементы в массив, а не заменять?

Tags: javascript

Как добавлять элементы в массив, а не заменять?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var layerGroup = [{
            layers_top: [{
                name: 'test',
                price: 105,
                height: 1,
                // img: 'lay.img',
            }],

        }];

        var nameArray = (el.value);


        layerGroup[0].layers_top.push({
                name: el.value,
                img: "img/layers/" + el.value + ".png",
                price: priceTop,
                height: heightLayerTop,
        })

        img.src = layerGroup[0].layers_top[1].img;

        console.log(layerGroup[0].layers_top[1].name);
        console.log(layerGroup[0].layers_top[1].price);
        console.log(layerGroup[0].layers_top[1].height);
        console.log(layerGroup[0].layers_top[1].img);
        console.log(layerGroup);
```

Comment: Вам стоит прочесть справочный раздел [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Да, извините, прочту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас переменная `layerGroup` - локальная в функции-обработчике. Вынесите ее наружу.